# Get GridView Object from Sender

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, sender, page-index-changed

I have multiple `GridView` on a page, and they are all pagable. I need to handle the paging in `OnPageIndexChanging` event, but I'd rather not write the same code for each `GridView`.

So how can I get the GridView object id from the sender? I'm trying to do something like the following....

```
protected void PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView gridView = (GridView)sender.ID;

    gridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    gridView.DataBind();
}
```

This way I could call the same event handler for all the GridViews and not have to write a new even handler for each one? I'm just not sure how to get the ***ID*** of the `GridView` firing the event :(

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's even simpler:

```
GridView gridView = (GridView)sender;
```

The `sender` argument is always the control that triggered the event.

Comment: Wow, that IS simple! I almost had it right! Thanks a lot, really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView gv= sender as GridView;

    if(gv!=null){
        gridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        gridView.DataBind();
    }
}
```